# select of select sql

Tags: php, sql

What it is the way to do a query in a way to select a select of something,

```
           SELECT a.Title,(results of another  SELECT ....),
                  FROM Table1 AS a
                  JOIN ........


           CREATE A VIEW v AS SELECT columnv,....
               FROM Table ,
```

And after I did

```
         SELECT a.Title,v.columnv,
              FROM Table1 AS a
              JOIN v......
```

with a View it's work but I have to use the result in PHP ,so can u suggest a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT `a`.`Title`, `b`.*
FROM `Table1` AS `a`
JOIN (SELECT your subquery here) AS `b` ON some condition here
```